# Python or bash if a domain name is registered

Tags: python, bash, api, dns

I was written this script for check if domain is responsive but from some reasons if there is more than around 50-  100 domains for check, script write me responsive page which don't need to be written in file

Here is my code:

cat ./domains/domains.all | sort | uniq  >> ./checked/unique.urls #filter unique domains
UNIQUE="./checked/unique.urls" #add unique domains in variable

touch ./checked/unresponsive.urls #create new file for unresponsive domains

while read p; do #while read line from $UNIQUE

```
if ! (dig $p @8.8.8.8 | grep  "ANSWER SECTION:"); then
    echo $p >> ./checked/unresponsive.urls
fi
sleep 5
```

done < $UNIQUE

I was think that sleep 5 will help me but it doesn't help and I tried with python too with `socket.gethostbyname()` but got the same.

I need suggestion about best way to check 100+ or 1000+ domains if they respond or if they are registered.

Suggestion can be free or paid API or any idea how can I fix my script or get accurate data

unique.urls example:

boutroofing.com
absolutely.net
absolutemadonna.com
absoluteradio.co.uk
acas.org.uk
accesshollywood.com
acclaimedmusic.net
accountkiller.com
acerdirect.co.uk
aceshowbiz.com
ackworth.com
acoustic-energy.co.uk
action.com
actionfraud.police.uk
activeboard.com
actualidadfutbol.com
acvm.co.uk
adambowie.com
adamcarolla.com
adamfi.co.uk

Comment: shouldn't you put `sleep 5` after `echo`? you're just delaying `echo` which I don't think its what you expect. and since you are in a `while` loop, i suggest putting `sleep 5` outside `if/fi` block

Comment: and by the way, what is `p` in your script?

Comment: Anzel thanks for suggestion. Going try put sleep in if/fi right now and check results. p is line from $UNIQUE variable. While read line from line(p) from $UNIQUE....

Comment: I have posted an answer before your comment, but the technique should work the same, you don't need to `sleep` neither. If you can show the complete code covering the variables, I can update my answer to fit yours

Comment: Here is full script now

Comment: With sleep outside if loop doing same, again gives me domains which respond. Will try remove !()

Comment: dig -f is batch mode.  +noall +question +answer to see failures, eg https://serverfault.com/a/619849/129952

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated: with UNIQUE variable using a for loop

use `if/else/fi` should work

```
UNIQUE="./checked/unique.urls" #add unique domains in variable
for line in $(cat $UNIQUE); do 
    if (dig "$line" @8.8.8.8|grep "ANSWER SECTION"); then 
        echo "OK"; 
    else 
        echo "$line" >> unresponsive.urls;
    fi; 
done;
```

#### with your sample urls

here is the outcome

```
$ sh checkURL.sh 
;; ANSWER SECTION:
OK
;; ANSWER SECTION:
OK
;; ANSWER SECTION:
OK
;; ANSWER SECTION:
OK
...

$ cat unresponsive.url 
boutroofing.com
ackworth.com
adamfi.co.uk
```

I can clearly run this script without problem and get the results

Comment: This script doing same like mine, just in for loop. My is while readline from $UNIQUE do ...

Comment: yes, but the tricks is i'm not doing `if !(...); then...`, I use `if (...); else ...; fi;`

Comment: Again same results with sleep or without, with If/else/fi or in while, with ! or without ! :( I tried with python, bash curl, dig... Maybe with host www.domain.com?

Comment: can you show part of your `unique.urls`? i wonder if the domains are not in each line format

Comment: I add it in my question

Comment: @Sasha112, I updated my post with results from your sample. My script has no problem getting results.

Comment: Yes, most results are ok but when i have bigger list like about 100+ or 1000+ domains then he put some responsive domains in unresponsive. I can give you all file but it will take you few hours

Comment: @Sasha112, ok but with your requirements for 50-100 domains, my answer should be accepted. If you have 1000+ domains, I suggest you creating 100 domains per file, and do a sleep between reading each (or run each file per hour via cron job). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a domain is registered by performing a DNS query for the domain's nameservers. If the domain is registered, it should have nameservers associated with it, and the DNS query will return their addresses. If the domain is not registered, the DNS query will fail.

```
#!/bin/bash
for domain in $(sed '/^$/d;/^#/d' domains.txt); do
        if [ -z "$(nslookup -type=ns $domain | awk '/nameserver/ {print $2}')" ]; then
                echo "$domain is not registered"
        else
                echo "$domain is registered"
        fi
done
```

Put all domains into domains.txt file. The script will ignore lines with # at the beginning, and an empty ones.